# OAuth2 configuration

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, postman

I am developing an application and I have already secured the api that I developed on ASP.net Core with Azure Ad implicit grant for the front end side.
Can I configure client credentials flow for accessing the API via Postman so that I don't have to authenticate when using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to implement implicit grant flow and client credentials flow in the same registered application. The reason behind this is  client credentials flow  require `client-secret` and implicit grant flow does not work with application having `client-secret`.

If you want to configure client credentials flow for above scenarion for accessing the API via Postman then please create a separate registered application in your tenant and [expose the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) such that you can access with postman.

Please feel free to ask if you need any more help :)

Comment: I already did that but when I'm trying to get a token with postman I'm getting this error: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Comment: In client credential flow we cannot dynamically request scopes i.e., The Application ID URI which you are assigning in your scope must look like `api://<your Application ID URI>/.default`.If it is not helping then please share me the api scope which you are trying to access and configured in your expose API such that I will check and update you the solution.

Comment: that's my scope: api://<Application ID>/Factures.Read. When i change the endpoint to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant Id>/oauth2/token instead of https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant Id>/oauth2/v2.0/token I can get a token but I get in the response that it is an invalid one.

Comment: Please try `api://<Application ID>/.default` instead of  `/Factures.Read` and update me.

Comment: I got a token but it's invalid : WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"

Comment: I believe you are still not able to access the API from the flow .please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration) which help in registering app as per the client credential flow. Also, we must not define scopes in exposed api mentioned in other service (as scopes here  is for users to login) we must only set an application uri there and can be accessible by `.default` instead of a defined scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help, finally, I have managed to make it work!